# error apt install beef-xss

Tags: linux, process-hacker

When I try to run "**$ apt install beef-xss**" in debiane 11 shows me this:

```
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree... Done

Reading state information... Done

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ruby-activesupport : Depends: ruby-tzinfo (>= 2.0) but 1.2.6-1 is to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken
```

I try to install(ruby-tzinfo) but not work , I belive this is issue in (ruby-activesupport) but  I don't know to solve it*

Comment: Do you have any held packages?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please note the title is not the question, and the body should not only be a paste of a log. You should write an informative title, put the question in the body, and also add to the body precisely what command you ran to get the output, the research that you have done, and what you have tried so far to resolve this.